# Updating one of the related entity

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I'm developing bulletin board system (as part of my training of asp.net mvc). I have a basic understanding of data modeling, but I have a doubt the way I've created my model. The core logic is to post ad with the following categories realty, auto and service. Initially I tried to use TPH approach, but then faced with problem of binding my models and automapper configuration. Now I think to use zero or one relationship.

I have a Ad model:

```
public class Ad
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual Realty Realty { get; set; }

    public virtual Auto Auto { get; set; }

    public virtual Service Service { get; set; }
}
```

Realty:

```
public class Realty
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("Ad")]
    public int AdID { get; set; }

    public string Type { get; set; }

    public string NumberOfRooms { get; set; }

    public virtual Ad Ad { get; set; }
}
```

Auto and service models have the same foreign key as the Realty model.

My db context:

```
public DbSet<Ad> Ads { get; set; }
public DbSet<Realty> Realties { get; set; }
public DbSet<Auto> Autos { get; set; }
public DbSet<Service> Services { get; set; }
```

I need update Ad model with one related model only. I'm using scaffolded controller action, which includes all related models:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "Title,Descirpiton,Realty,Auto,Service")] Ad ad)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Ads.Add(ad);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    ViewBag.ID = new SelectList(db.Autos, "AdID", "CarType", ad.ID);
    ViewBag.ID = new SelectList(db.Realties, "AdID", "Type", ad.ID);
    ViewBag.ID = new SelectList(db.Services, "AdID", "ServiceType", ad.ID);
    return View(ad);
}
```

The problem, that it makes possible to post Ad with all related models together. Before diving deep I wanted to ensure that I'm on a right way of doing this.

Thanks.

Comment: This looks like it may be a textbook example of Table Per Type (TPT) modeling.  https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close. Based on what it looks like you're trying to do you should be using a table-per-type model. You create the base (Ad) and then inherit from it to create the sub-types.

```
public class Ad
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

[Table("Realty")]
public class Realty : Ad
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string NumberOfRooms { get; set; }
}
```

Your context remains the same. You can now create the appropriate sub-type when you know what kind of ad is being created.

```
var ad = new Realty();
ad.Title = "...";
ad.Description = "...";
ad.Type = "...";
ad.NumberOfRooms = "...";
```

You can retrieve specific ad types by using the specific type on the context.

```
db.Realty.ToList();
```

Or you can retrieve all the ads and interrogate the types as you loop over them.

```
var ads = db.Ads.ToList();

foreach(var ad in ads)
{
    if(ad is Realty)
        // do Realty stuff
    else if (ad is Auto)
        // do Auto stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks Craig, one more question then. I want to implement single create action for appropriate sub type, depends on a user selection in view. In which direction should I seek for? Thanks.

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Once you've got your entity classes fully implemented you should probably post a new question with more detail than can be addressed in a comment.